# Text not wrapping to next line within list item

Tags: html, css

Have a quick look at the main menu drop down, for example About Us, the child item is not wrapping to the next line in the list item, instead it runs out of line of the list item. I've set an automatic height. A width on the UL LI and anchor. I've tried using

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

But that trims part of the word. I would greatly appreciated getting this text to sit within the list item. Height of the list item isn't an issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why don't you leave the width as is, all li items would be the length of the largest text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `white-space: nowrap;` from the `#section-header #zone-menu ul.nice-menu-down li`
and change the padding on `#section-header #zone-menu ul.nice-menu a` to `padding: 1em;`

Comment: Thanks Gaby! Worked great, I completely missed that, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `word-wrap:break-word`?